# C# setting ImageCodec and Encoder Parameters for Image.Save()

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm writing a program the from some text file inputs outputs a large number of image files.
Currently these images are being created and saved with

```
Parallel.ForEach(set, c =>
{
    using (Bitmap b = Generate_Image(c, Watermark))
    {
         //The encoder needs some set up to function properly
         string s = string.Format("{0:0000}", c.Index);
         string filepath = $@"{Directory}\{s}.png";
         //best quality comes from manually configuring the codec and 
         //encoder used for the image saved                                                       
          b.Save(filepath, ImageFormat.Png);
     }
});
```

However I noticed that `b.Save()` has an overload for taking an `ImageCodeInfo` and an `EncoderProperties`, which should be able to produce a higher quality image output (the image quality is paramount to the program).

However, I haven't been able to find anywhere what needs to be done to create these objects to then pass in as parameters, at least not ones that work even in the Microsoft Documents, strangely enough, their samples didn't compile. So if I may ask how does one uses the method overload of Image.Save(Filepath,encoder,settings)?

Thank you in advance for any help offered.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small method to retrieve that information in my own code:

```
    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
            if (codec.MimeType == mimeType)
                return codec;

        return null;
    }
```

And this is how I use it to save a Jpeg:

```
        ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        if (jpegCodec == null)
            return;

        EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);

        image.Save(imagePath, jpegCodec, encoderParameters);
```

Its not used to save a Png:

```
     image.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Png);
```

You'll need the following namespaces:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

Also, I should mention, Png is a lossless image format. That is why there is no encoder parameters for it, because you cannot achieve better quality than lossless.

For the highest quality when working with the `Graphics` class, make sure you set the following properties:

```
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

Comment: so to clarify, if i'm saving it to a png I wont have to bother setting any such parameters up? just using the ImageFormat.png gives the best possible results?
Thankyou for this by the way, was worried I'd ruin the processors hard work using the high quality bitmap settings by saving it in some lossy way.

Comment: Yes, you can't save better than lossless. In other words, it will save whatever you have in your Bitmap or image object directly to disk without changing a single pixel. If you save an image as a Png and you feel the result appears to be of low quality, you have to look at how the image was drawn or manipulated because the save transfered every pixel exactly as it was when you requested the save.

Comment: Yeah I wan't having any issues with the quality output, they looked exactly how they were supposed to, just wanted to double check, thanks for this.